# Hbase Hadoop cluster.. java.io.IOException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodExceptio

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am trying to set up a hbase cluster which is running on top of a hadoop cluster.
Both clusters are up and running but
when I try to create a table in Hbase client..am seeing the following error in the logs!!

compute-0-11 : is the name node for the hadoop cluster.

```
2012-03-18 01:18:54,696 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils: 
Unable to create version file at hdfs://compute-0-11:9000/hbase, retrying:
java.io.IOException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.ClientProtocol.create(java.lang.String, org.apache.hadoop.fs.permission.FsPermission, java.lang.String, boolean, boolean, short, long)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1605)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1384)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1059)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1382)
```

Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually it happens when there is a mismatch between versions of software in your cluster and your job / client. 
Errors like class was expected / interface found usually happens when different versions of hadoop APIs are used (napred vs napreduce).